# Limit number of clicks on a button per day

Tags: java, android

I would like to limit the number of clicks on a button per day (5 times) this button allows you to turn a wheel

**Wheel activity**

```
 ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    final SharedPreferences coins = getSharedPreferences("Rewards", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final LuckyWheelView luckyWheelView = (LuckyWheelView) findViewById(R.id.luckyWheel);
    findViewById(R.id.play).setEnabled(true);
    findViewById(R.id.play).setAlpha(1f);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    weekday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    todayString = year + "" + month + "" + day;
    final SharedPreferences spinChecks = getSharedPreferences("SPINCHECK", 0);
    final boolean currentDay = spinChecks.getBoolean(todayString, false);
```

**Wheel xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back1now"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font"
    android:text="@string/play"
    android:textAppearance="@style/play"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Relativespin"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.61" />
```

These are the two codes, please help me.
Thank you

new (add code)

```
findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                int index = getRandomIndex();
                luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);
                SharedPreferences.Editor spins = spinChecks.edit();
                spins.putBoolean(todayString, true);
                spins.apply();
                findViewById(R.id.play).setEnabled(false);
                findViewById(R.id.play).setAlpha(.5f);
```

I added a last piece of code (which I could do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of using a boolean for `spinChecks.getBoolean(todayString, false);`, you can use an `Int` value. You would then, validate whether the `spinChecks.getInt(todayString, 0)` call is higher than 4, if so, just call `playButton.seEnabled(false)`, otherwise, call `setEnabled(true)`.

Comment: I updated the code (the last code add to the post) please tell me now how to integrate your code

Comment: @GNAKALEHACKER it's basically the same idea, just do not use boolean and use an Int count instead. Rather than using spin.putBoolean(todayString, true) in your OnClickListener, use putInt(todayString, spinChecks.getInt(todayString, 0) + 1), that way you would be adding 1 every click. And as I explained, just check if that value is higher than 4 and mark your Button as disabled.